# How can I loop through each record of a text file to replace a string of characters

Tags: powershell

I have a large .txt file containing records where a date string in each record needs to be incremented by 2 days which will then update the field to the right of it which contains dashes --------- with that date. For example, a record contains the following record data:

1440149049845_20191121000000 11/22/2019 -------- 0.000 0.013

I am replacing the -------- dashes with 11/24/2019 (2 days added to the date 11/22/2019) so that it shows as:

1440149049845_20191121000000 11/22/2019  11/24/2019 0.000 0.013

I have the replace working on a single record but need to loop through the entire .txt file to update all of the records.  Here is what I tried:

```
$inputRecords = get-content '\\10.12.7.13\vipsvr\Rancho\MRDF_Report\_Report.txt'

foreach ($line in $inputRecords)  
 {
    $item -match '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}' 
    $inputRecords -replace '-{2,}',([datetime]$matches.0).adddays(2).tostring('MM/dd/yyyy') -replace '\b0\.000\b','0.412'
 }
```

I get an PS error stating:   "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"

Comment: [1] where is `$item` coming from? [2] your code will run the `-replace` once for EVERY LINE. [*grin*] you likely otta use the match on the previous line to decide IF you should run the `-replace` line. [3] you are running the `-replace` on the ENTIRE collection. you likely otta use `$Line` instead of `$inputRecords`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but why are we using RegEx for something this simple?

I can see it if there are differently formatted lines in the file, you'd want to make sure you aren't manipulating unintended lines, but that's not indicated in the question.  Even still, it doesn't seem like you need to match anything within the line itself.  It seems like it's delimited on spaces which would make a simple split a lot easier.

Example:

```
$File = "C:\temp\Test.txt"
$Output =
ForEach( $Line in Get-Content $File)
{
$TmpArray = $Line.Split(' ')
$TmpArray[2] = (Get-Date $TmpArray[1]).AddDays(2).ToString('M/dd/yyyy')
$TmpArray -join ' '
}
```

The 3rd element in the array do the calculation and reassign the value...

Notice there's no use of the += operator which is very slow compared to simply assigning the output to a variable.  I wouldn't make a thing out of it but considering we don't know how big the file is...  Also the String format given before 'mm/dd/yyyy' will result in 00 for the month like for example '00/22/2019', so I changed that to 'M/dd/yyyy'

You can still add logic to skip unnecessary lines if it's needed...

You can send $Output to a file with something like `$Output | Out-File <FilePath>`

Or this can be converted to a single pipeline that outputs directly to a file using `| ForEach{...}` instead of `ForEach(.. in ..)`  If the file is truly huge and holding $Output in memory is an issue this is a good alternative.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly had the right idea, but here are a few suggested changes, but not exactly in this order:

1. Use a new file instead of trying to replace the old file.
2. Iterate a line at a time, replace the ------, write to the new file.
3. Use '-match' instead of '-replace', because as you will see below that you need to manipulate the capture more than a simple '-replace' allows.
4. Use [datetime]::parseexact instead of trying to just force cast the captured text.

```
[string[]]$inputRecords = get-content ".\linesource.txt"
[string]$outputRecords

foreach ($line in $inputRecords) {
    [string]$newLine = ""
    [regex]$logPattern = "^([\d_]+) ([\d/]+) (-+) (.*)$"
    if ($line -match $logPattern) {
        $origDate = [datetime]::parseexact($Matches[2], 'mm/dd/yyyy', $null)
        $replacementDate = $origDate.adddays(2)

        $newLine  = $Matches[1]
        $newLine += " " + $origDate.toString('mm/dd/yyyy')
        $newLine += " " + $replacementDate.toString('mm/dd/yyyy')
        $newLine += " " + $Matches[4]
    } else {
        $newLine = $line
    }
    $outputRecords += "$newLine`n"
}

$outputRecords.ToString()
```

Even if you don't use the whole solution, hopefully at least parts of it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggested code from adamt8 and Steven, I added to 2 echo statements to show what gets displayed in the variables $logpattern and $line since it is not recognizing the pattern of characters to be updated.  This is what displays from the echo:

Options   MatchTimeout      RightToLeft

CalNOD01    1440151020208_20191205000000    12/06/2019  12/10/2019
   None -00:00:00.0010000       False
CalNOD01    1440151020314_20191205000000    12/06/2019  --------
   None -00:00:00.0010000       False

this is the rendered output:

CalNOD01    1440151020208_20191205000000    12/06/2019  12/10/2019
CalNOD01    1440151020314_20191205000000    12/06/2019  --------

This is the code that was used:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9LWD.png)